# Edit resource file after project was built

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, resources

I want to edit file with some parameters after I build the project. I have file on "Assets/Resources" and read it with:

```
TextAsset txt = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("login", typeof(TextAsset));
```

After I build project, I go to Reources folder on build, but I don't find file "login".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your files to be available after the build, you need to use https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html. The regular assets get build into the project.